# How can I set a default category for a custom post type in wordpress?

Tags: php

I am trying to put together some functions in wordpress which will allow me to add a custom post type *and* associate a default category *and* post on the posts page.

So far I have been able to create a custom post type, and as far as I can tell I am associating a default category. However, the posts do not show up in the post feed.

Here is the code I have pieced together:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_prayer_request' );

function create_prayer_request() {
    register_post_type( 'prayer_request',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Prayer Requests' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Prayer Request' ),
                'add_new' => __( 'Add New Prayer Request' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Prayer Request' ),
                'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Prayer Request' ),
                'new_item' => __( 'New Prayer Request' ),
                'view' => __( 'View Prayer Requests' ),
                'view_item' => __( 'View Prayer Request' ),
                'search_items' => __( 'Search Prayer Requests' ),
                'not_found' => __( 'No prayer requests found' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No prayer requests found in Trash' ),
            ),
            'public' => true,
        )
    );
}

function save_custom_post ( $post_id, $post = null ) {
    if ( !$post ) $post = get_post($post_id);
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_posts', $post->ID ) ) return;
    if ( 'prayer_request' != $post->post_type ) return;
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    wp_set_object_terms( $post->ID, 'prayer-request', 'prayer_request' );
}
add_action( "save_post", "save_custom_post", 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with 'save_post' is that it gets called when you actually change something on the post edit page, if you just click the update button without changing anything, it doesn't get called. So, i would say use 'pre_post_update' action hook instead of 'save_post' or use both. Also for debugging try put some test code in your custom function and test it to make sure it is being called.

Answer (score 1):

After `'public' => true,`
add `'taxonomies' => array("category")`
and get this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_prayer_request' );

function create_prayer_request() {
    register_post_type( 'prayer_request',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Prayer Requests' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Prayer Request' ),
                'add_new' => __( 'Add New Prayer Request' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Prayer Request' ),
                'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Prayer Request' ),
                'new_item' => __( 'New Prayer Request' ),
                'view' => __( 'View Prayer Requests' ),
                'view_item' => __( 'View Prayer Request' ),
                'search_items' => __( 'Search Prayer Requests' ),
                'not_found' => __( 'No prayer requests found' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No prayer requests found in Trash' ),
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'taxonomies' => array("category")
        )
    );
}

function save_custom_post ( $post_id, $post = null ) {
    if ( !$post ) $post = get_post($post_id);
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_posts', $post->ID ) ) return;
    if ( 'prayer_request' != $post->post_type ) return;
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    wp_set_object_terms( $post->ID, 'prayer-request', 'prayer_request' );
}
add_action( "save_post", "save_custom_post", 10, 2 );
```